# Controller not loaded from different assembly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, controller, assemblies

I'm trying to load a `Controller` from a different assembly but I'm stuck here.

I have two projects:

1. Web application
2. Class library

In the web application I defined a `Route`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Root", "root/{Action}", 
                  new {Controller = "Root", Action = "Index" });
```

Now when I hit the following URL, the route is matched, however a 404 error is thrown. **Can anybody tell me why this is happening?** (p.s. the `RootController` is located in the class library)

```
http://webapp/root
```

I've tried adding a custom controller factory:

```
public class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext reqContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        // reqContext.Route is correct and has the "Root" route loaded
        // controllerType seems to be null ??

        // if I break execution here and manually set controllerType to
        // typeof(ClassLibrary.RootController) and continue from there,
        // then everything works as expected... 

        // So this method is being called without controllerType... but why??
    }
}
```

I also tried adding a `namespaces` property to the route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Root", "root/{Action}", 
              new {
                Controller = "Root", 
                Action = "Index", 
                Namespaces = new[] { typeof(RootController).Namespace }                     
              });
```

Comment: @Max Toro, please see my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much debugging and frustration I found that the controller class was declared `private` which doesn't work in the scenario.

Even though my `ControllerFactory` is in the same namespace, the classes that create *controller caches* aren't. Thus the request to `GetControllerInstance`, which is made by the `DefaultControllerFactory` base class can't find the `RootController` class.

Declaring the `RootController` as `public` solves the issue.

Comment: DefaultControllerFactory will search all types in assemblies returned by BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies, then preform this filter `return ((((t != null) && t.IsPublic) && (t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !t.IsAbstract)) && typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t));
}
` to find controller.